# Express pass in Sequelize model in where clause

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a Follow record via:

```
const find = {where: {user: req.user, gameId: id}}
const follow = await Follow.findOrCreate(find);
```

however, this doesn't work. It tells me:

```
 Error: Invalid value User
```

But, doing

```
const find = {where: {userId: req.user.id, gameId: id}}
const follow = await Follow.findOrCreate(find);
```

works! I'm curious, do I have to explicitly pass in `userId`? Can sequelize not infer what i mean from the definition of the association in the models? In the models I have:

```
Follow.belongsTo(models.User, {
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  as: 'user'
});
```

and

```
    User.hasMany(models.Follow, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as: 'follows',
    });
```

Comment: I think you should remove the express tag and add the sequelize.js tag

Comment: @UchihaItachi good call, done.